# How to add an arraylist as datasource to devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, arraylist, devexpress

I have an Arraylist containing an amount of objects. 
All these Objects have a name, size...
Now I want every object to be shown as a row in a grid control.
If I write:

```
gridControl.DataSource = ArrayList;
```

I get the right amount of rows, but without filling. How can I add the Values of each objects attributes?

```
ArrayList dataSource = new ArrayList();
dataSource.Clear();

foreach(FileInfo element in dir.GetFiles())
{           
     dataSourceEntry item = new dataSourceEntry();
     item.fileCreateDate = element.CreationTime.Date;
     item.fileName = element.Name;
     item.check = true;
     dataSource.Add(item);
}
gridFiles.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `List<FileInfo>()` instead of an arrayList?

Comment: why should that make any difference? I already got the Datasource, I only need the connection between the attributes and the columns

Comment: Another point: I don't know if DevExpress uses this to, but shouldn't there be a `gridFiles.DataBind();` method somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any DataBind() - methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is hard to extract column's information from `ArrayList`, I suggest you use generic `List<T>` instead (or `BindingList<T>` if you want to track element's changes):

```
List<dataSourceEntry> dataSource = new List<dataSourceEntry>();

foreach(FileInfo element in dir.GetFiles())
{           
     dataSourceEntry item = new dataSourceEntry();
     item.fileCreateDate = element.CreationTime.Date;
     item.fileName = element.Name;
     item.check = true;
     dataSource.Add(item);
}
gridFiles.DataSource = dataSource;
gridFiles.MainView.PopulateColumns();
```

P.S. Anyway, your approach with `ArrayList` should work correctly when the data source assigned to grid is not empty.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but I don't have access to that "populateColumns" method.